# Prolog - translating operators

Tags: prolog, operators, predicate, operator-precedence

I have defined the following operators:

```
:- op(200, xfx, plus).
:- op(100, xfx, times).
```

I want to implement a predicate translate/2 so that a given term consisting of only numbers and the operators plus and times, so that these operators will be translated to their corresponding arithmetical operators: + and *.

For instance:

```
?- translate((4 plus 5), Result).
   Result = 4 + 5.

?- translate(((3 times 2) times 7 plus 4), Result).
   Result = (3 * 2) * 7 + 4.

?-translate((5 times 3 plus 4 times 5)), Result).
  Result = 5 * 3 + 4 * 5.
```

update: Allright so the code Ive come up so far with is:

```
replace([], _, _, []).

replace([El1|List], El1, El2, [El2|Result]) :-
replace(List, El1, El2, Result), !.

replace([H|List], El1, El2, [H|Result]) :-
replace(List, El1, El2, Result). %replaces an element in a list with 
                                  %another element.


translate(Term, ListResult2):-
  Term =.. ListResult,
  replace(ListResult, times, *, ListResult1),
  replace(ListResult1, plus, +, ListResult2). %This will make a list of a 
                                              % a term and replace the
                                              %operators the right way.
```

Sorry for not having added more specific comments on how my clauses work. The idea here is to produce a list in which te operators are replaced by the the corresponding terms. My problem is that the ouput is a list instead of a term. Is there a way of reversing what I did with the =.. operator???

Comment: What have you tried yourself? What is not working? What problems you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution, it was something syntactical that i was missing out on. I forgot that the =.. operator can provide solutions for both sides on the term. so X =.. [1,2,3] will convert the list [1,2,3] into the corresponding term and vice versa. The solution looks like this:

```
replace([], _, _, []).

replace([El1|List], El1, El2, [El2|Result]) :-
replace(List, El1, El2, Result), !.

replace([H|List], El1, El2, [H|Result]) :-
replace(List, El1, El2, Result).


translate(Term, TrueResult):-
  Term =.. ListResult,
  replace(ListResult, times, *, ListResult1),
  replace(ListResult1, plus, +, ListResult2),
  TrueResult =.. ListResult2.
```

Comment: What if your examples are recursive? Like `(a plus b) times c`?

Comment: Celebrated too early... So i will need to check i plus/times is a part of the member of the list and then replace instead of just seeing plus/times as being a possible member.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may suit your needs:

```
:- op(200, yfx, plus).
:- op(100, yfx, times).

translate(Z, Z1):-
  (
    nonvar(Z),
    Z \= _ plus _,
    Z \= _ times _
  ) -> Z1=Z ;
  (
    member(Z-Z1, [(X plus Y)-(X1 + Y1), (X times Y)-(X1 * Y1)]),
    translate(X, X1),
    translate(Y, Y1)
  ).
```

Test cases:

```
?- translate((4 plus 5), Result).
Result = 4+5 
?- translate(((3 times 2) times 7 plus 4), Result).
Result = 3*2*7+4
?- translate((5 times 3 plus 4 times 5), Result).
Result = 5*3+4*5
?- translate((a plus b) times c, Result).
Result = (a+b)*c
?- translate(5 times (3 plus 4) times 5, Result).
Result = 5* (3+4)*5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Do you think it can also be done with the =.. approach that I showed above or will it end up being too unpragmatic??

Comment: @WillemvanderSpek: I think you might get it working using `=..`, although you should modify your procedure to recursively call itself with each operand.